# Two separate Sharepoint Servers pointing to the same Content Database

Tags: database

Is it possible to have two separate Sharepoint web servers pointing to a single content database on a separate server?

I do not want to do this concurrently.  If I switch one web server off, then attach the production content database on the second web server, will this cause any problems?  Can I switch back and forth without any issue?

Comment: That sounds like a very scary thing to do with a production database... why are you trying to do this?

Comment: You're just asking for trouble. This is not a supported configuration. Use SQL clustering to deal with availability.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't you add both WFEs into the farm and use load balancer rules to route traffic through only 1 WFE at a time?  If one needs to be taken out, the load balancer can shift all requests to the other WFE?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds horrible.

I assume it is not the traditional '2 SharePoint servers in the same farm connecting to a single content DB scenario', or is it?

Comment: Its a bit complex.  The database will sit on a shared environment and i need to figure out a method of contingency.  If the database server has to move it should be transparent and out of my control, however we also need to contingency server, which will need to point at the same server address.  Part of testing this will involve pointing the contingency server to the current database.  I wanted to know if this was feasible without messing with the content database before going ahead with it, or trying to figure out another method.  Its a relatively small installation.

Comment: So basically you want two front end servers available but only want to use one? I'd think you'd want them to be a part of the same farm.